# Use Unix JOIN command to merge two files

Tags: unix, join

This isn't working like I expect, despite all research. I must be missing something...

File 1...

```
# cat file1.csv
1       123     JohnDoe
1       456     BobDylan
1       789     BillyJean
```

File 2...

```
# cat file2.csv
111     123     DaddyDoe
222     456     DaddyDylan
666     777     Stranger
555     789     DaddyJean
444     888     Stranger
333     999     Stranger
```

I am trying to join on both the second fields. When I perform a left outer join and only include fields from the first file, everything seems dandy.

```
# join -1 2 -2 2 -a 1 -o 1.2 1.3 file1.csv file2.csv
123 JohnDoe
456 BobDylan
789 BillyJean
```

But as soon as I include a field from the second file, it all goes wack.

```
# join -1 2 -2 2 -a 1 -o 1.2 1.3 2.3 file1.csv file2.csv
 DaddyDoeoe
 DaddyDylann
789 BillyJean DaddyJean
```

The last line looks perfect! What's up with the others? Any idea? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is my attempt with actual CSVs.

```
# cat file1.csv
1,123,JohnDoe
1,456,BobDylan
1,789,BillyJean

# cat file2.csv
111,123,DaddyDoe
222,456,DaddyDylan
666,777,Stranger
555,789,DaddyJean
444,888,Stranger
333,999,Stranger

# join -t, -1 2 -2 2 -a 1 -o 1.2 1.3 2.3 file1.csv file2.csv
,DaddyDoeoe
,DaddyDylann
789,BillyJean,DaddyJean
```

Comment: what version OS are you using? And are the columns really delimited with ','s, per the file extension?

Comment: -o option needs to be quotes, or you can use comma delimited instead if white space.  Not sure if that is the issue, but seems to be a partial issue,

Comment: @shellter Unix 3.5. They are tab delimited files. I took out the commas when trying to troubleshoot. @Suroot I gave that a shot but it didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used the `-a` option.

> `-a` file_number
>
> In addition to the default output, produce a line for each unpairable line in file file_number.

In addition, the odd overwriting behavior indicates that you have embedded carriage returns (`\r`).  I would examine those fies closely with `cat -v` or a text editor that doesn't try to be "smart" about Windows files.

Comment: Hi @geekosaur, yes this is what I intend.

Comment: @Nate: So why are you confused? You're getting what you asked for; as with an SQL outer join, the fields from the other file are NULL (empty).

Comment: there are three matches between the files: 123, 456, 789. There should be no missing data. Not only that, but the first two output lines have the names from the two files mashed together.

Comment: Ahhh, I got it.  You have lines with mixed newlines. Expanding response.

Comment: @geekosuar, you're a life saver. It was the carriage returns. I switched my FTP app to ASCII transfer from Binary and now I am golden. Thanks!

Comment: how can i use this for full outer join?

Answer (score 2):

Use the correct 'field' separator in your command.

When I changed your data to true csv, and used

```
join -t, -1 2 -2 2 -a 1 -o 1.2 1.3 2.3 file1.csv file2.csv
# ---^^^
```

I got

```
123,JohnDoe,DaddyDoe
456,BobDylan,DaddyDylan
789,BillyJean,DaddyJean
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @shellter. I did this but got very similar results. I've added the code to my question.

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing this command line why not use paste?
paste -d, file1 file2 >> file3

the -d arugment is the delimiter