# ValueError: array is too big

Tags: python

I am trying to merge two excel files using the following code and encountering the error of `ValueError: array is too big; arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize is larger than the maximum possible size.`

```
import pandas as pd

file1 = pd.read_excel("file1.xlsx")
file2 = pd.read_excel("file2.xlsx")

file3 = file1.merge(file2, on="Input E-mail", how="outer")

file3.to_excel("merged1.xlsx")
```

File size is ~100MB+~100MB, Available Ram is 9GB (of 16GB)

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit Python?

Comment: Currently using 32-bit

Comment: Switch to 64-bit, then.

Comment: Did you try other packages than pandas to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your resulting dataframe can be much larger than your two input ones. Simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

values = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,1,1,1], "value": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]})

users = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,1,1], "users": ["Amy", "Bob", "Dan"]})

big_table = pd.merge(users, values, how="outer")

print big_table
```

Result:

```
     id  users    value
0     1   Amy       a
1     1   Amy       b
2     1   Amy       c
3     1   Amy       d
4     1   Bob       a
5     1   Bob       b
6     1   Bob       c
7     1   Bob       d
8     1   Dan       a
9     1   Dan       b
10    1   Dan       c
11    1   Dan       d
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is intended and I am looking for the Result exactly what you described but since the file size is 100MB it is giving an error of "array is too big". Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: @user3783174 If you need the whole merged dataframe, the only way to solve this issue is to get machine with more RAM. However, do you need it all? Maybe you can filter the rows that you are most interested in before merging?

Comment: Unfortunately Yes. I need all the data. Can you suggest me the required RAM?

Comment: I don't know. It would really depend on how your input files are structured. And even if I new that, it would be pretty hard to figure out.

Comment: I just tried the same in 64 bit and got an error as "MemoryError". Could you suggest an alternate way to deal this?

Comment: No promises, but if you are on a unix system, you could try to merge the table in command line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300271/merge-join-two-tables-fast-linux-command-line.

Comment: However, I would rethink if you need a table that big. Even if you can create it, how will it be used?