# perl matching two columns from different tables

Tags: perl

I have a table like this with 3 columns, called table1

```
1       2       A
2       3       B
4       5       D
```

I have another table with one column, called table2, looking like this

```
A
B
E
F
```

If there is a match between table2 and third column of table1, I want to print the matching line as it is to a new table called output, which in this case should look like this

```
1    2    A
2    3    B
```

I'm writing in Perl and think I should do this using hash. So I tried the following

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $table1,'<',"table1.txt");
open(my $table2,'<',"table2.txt");
open(my $output,'+>',"output.txt");

my %hash = ();

while (<$table2>){
    chomp;
    my $keyfield = $_;
    push @{$hash{keyfield}};
}
seek $table1,0,0;
while (<$table1>){
     chomp;
     my @cols = split(/\t/);
     my $keyfield = $cols[2];
     if (exists($hash{$keyfield})) {
        print $output $_, "\n";
 }
 }
```

This approach worked before, however now I had to modify it slightly. I get the warning: useless use of push with no values at line13 (which is the line where my push is). And my output is empty. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that there is a Unix command `join` that you can use to do this. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393333/use-unix-join-command-to-merge-two-files

Happy perl-ing, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$hash{$keyfield} = 1` to create an association instead of `push`.

Per [tip from @Sobrique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167802/perl-matching-two-columns-from-different-tables/30167980#comment48443488_30167980), you can also use `$hash{$keyfield}++` which will let you determine later whether key exists and also give you a number of occurrences.

Comment: Would normally use `++` by default, rather than `=1` simply because it works in the same way for boolean tests, but makes a count otherwise.

Comment: @Sobrique, great tip about `++`!